# SQL Server table league

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to build a table league from matches (scores and rounds).

I succceeded from my SQL Server database to calculate points for each teams and matches but I would like now to generate a table league.. (football)

Some one can help me please?

```
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.jos_joomleague_matches.match_id, dbo.jos_joomleague_clubs.name AS Team, jos_joomleague_clubs_1.name AS Team2, 
                      dbo.jos_joomleague_matches.match_date, dbo.jos_joomleague_matches.matchpart1_result, dbo.jos_joomleague_matches.matchpart2_result, 
                      dbo.jos_joomleague_rounds.name, 
                      CASE WHEN dbo.jos_joomleague_matches.matchpart1_result > dbo.jos_joomleague_matches.matchpart2_result THEN 3 WHEN dbo.jos_joomleague_matches.matchpart1_result
                       = dbo.jos_joomleague_matches.matchpart2_result THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ptsclub1HOME, 
                      CASE WHEN dbo.jos_joomleague_matches.matchpart2_result > dbo.jos_joomleague_matches.matchpart1_result THEN 3 WHEN dbo.jos_joomleague_matches.matchpart2_result
                       = dbo.jos_joomleague_matches.matchpart1_result THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ptsclub2AWAY
FROM         dbo.jos_joomleague_rounds INNER JOIN
                      dbo.jos_joomleague_clubs AS jos_joomleague_clubs_1 INNER JOIN
                      dbo.jos_joomleague_matches INNER JOIN
                      dbo.jos_joomleague_clubs ON dbo.jos_joomleague_matches.matchpart1 = dbo.jos_joomleague_clubs.id ON 
                      jos_joomleague_clubs_1.id = dbo.jos_joomleague_matches.matchpart2 ON dbo.jos_joomleague_rounds.id = dbo.jos_joomleague_matches.round_id
ORDER BY dbo.jos_joomleague_matches.match_date
```

`

Comment: Show us (1) Your current table structure and a few rows of example data (2) Your desired results.

Comment: What is the question?  You describe something you want but not anything you have done, no table structures, no starting point.

Answer (score 3):

Start with an natural language description of your problem before you create tables.  Think about the relationships:

A `league` has many `teams`.  A `match` has two `teams` that play on a given `date` and has a specific `outcome`.

I see three tables: `league`, `team`, and `match`.  Start with those.

You're premature if you're thinking about queries already.  Get the basic table structure right first.